# Meteor form state not being saved

Tags: meteor

I'm having problems trying to make a reactive form. When I insert data into one collection, the other select is refreshed also. This happens with input fields also, everything gets cleared when I update one of the bound collections.

Is this supposed to happen?

My test code:

```html
<template name="test">
  <form class="form-horizontal well" id="test-form">
    <select class="input-xlarge" name="item_id">
      {{#each types}}
        <option value="{{_id}}">{{name}}</option>
      {{/each}}
    </select>
    <select class="input-xlarge" name="category_id">
      {{#each categories}}
        <option value="{{_id}}">{{name}}</option>
      {{/each}}
    </select>
  </form>
</template>
```

And my helpers are:

```js
Template.accounts.type = ->
  Types.find({}).fetch()

Template.accounts.categories = ->
  Categories.find({}).fetch()
```

Comment: One working (but hacky) solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012343/html-select-loses-selection-when-re-rendered-in-meteor/13013326#13013326%20%22One%20working,%20but%20hacky%20solution%20is%20here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a limitation of Meteor right now, hopefully it'll be resolved in the future.

As discussed on irc, some ways to get around it:

1. Separate them into different templates
2. Wrap them in a helper that calls `Meteor.ui.chunk`.
3. Use a session variable to track the currently selected state. For example:

   ```
   Template.accounts.events = {
     'change #category_id': function() { 
        Session.set('selected_category_id', $(this).val());
     }
   }
   ```

(and code to initially select the value in `Session.get('selected_category_id')` if not `undefined` in the template).