# HTML Select loses selection when re-rendered in Meteor

Tags: html, select, rendering, meteor

I have a couple of HTML  elements on a page. Whenever the page context is invalidated and it re-renders the  elements are re-rendered with no visual cue of the selected option.

If I check for the selection using $('.select1 option:selected') the selected option is returned. However, it is not rendered as selected. If it's a drop-down, then the first element shows up. If it's a multi-line select, the first (firefox) or last (chrome) element shows up with a greyed out select line on it.

If I then click the selected element a second time, it shows up as selected.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I implemented the solution here: [Meteor form state not being saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092704/meteor-form-state-not-being-saved)

Store the selected value in a session variable on click:

```
Template.packageViewer.events({
    'change .tagselect': function(){
        Session.set('tag', $('.tagselect :selected').html());}
    ,
    'change .groupselect': function(){
       Session.set('group', $('.groupselect :selected').html());}
    ,
    'change .packageselect': function(){
        Session.set('package', $('.packageselect :selected').val());}
});
```

Then set the select selected value in the post-render function:

```
Template.packageViewer.rendered = function(){
    $('.groupselect').val(Session.get('group'));
    $('.tagselect').val(Session.get('tag'));
}
```

Hacky, but works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use $('.select1').trigger("change"); function.