# Select-Tag Default Selection Ignored by IE8 when using Handlebars with Meteor

Tags: internet-explorer-8, meteor, handlebars.js

I created a blank Meteor project and tried to put a <SELECT> tag in the handlebar HTML file.  This works in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, but IE8 ignores the selected="selected" attribute:

```
<head><title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <select>
    <option>abc</option>
    <option selected="selected">def</option>
    <option>ghi</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

So IE8 displays "abc" as the selected option.

I have also tried writing a Handlebar helper function, with the same result:

```
<head><title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{{hbarselect}}}
</body>

// in the js file
Handlebars.registerHelper("hbarselect", function(value) {
    var ret = '';
    ret = '<select>';
    ret += '<option>abc</option>';
    ret += '<option selected="selected">def</option>';
    ret += '<option>ghi</option>';
    ret += '</select>';
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(ret);;
  });
```

If I ignore Handlebars completely and just write a simple HTML file, then IE8 behaves properly:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<select>
<option>abc</option>
<option selected="selected">def</option>
<option>ghi</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there something I need to know about Handlebars to make this work?  How can I fix this?

Comment: I see the same problem in IE9 too, investigating (#meteor on IRC might help). This is my code currently: https://gist.github.com/4120133

Comment: Looks like a possible bug, so filed one: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/496

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this workaround for losing selected states might help?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13013326/1758461